# Kitchen Cabinets And Dry Wall Screws

Tags: drywall, installation, cabinets

I've got some kitchen cabinets that were hung using 4", course threaded, dry wall screwed.  At every stud there is a screw at the top and bottom of the cabinet.  Additionally, each cabinet is joined to the one on either side 3-6 3", dry-wall screws.  I hope I'm explaining that correctly.

Anyway, after having/using the cabinets for years, without any problems, I read an article about how bad it is to use drywall screws for anything other than drywall.  I was told by the guy at the Home Depot that my family is seconds away from death because it's a miracle they held at all; and that I need to replace them ASAP, with these 4" 'Gold Screws' he sold me.

I've replaced all of the 4" drywall screws with the gold screws.  My question is about the drywall screws used to keep the face of the cabinets flush....they are only 3" drywall screws; but they've been covered with wood putty and sanded.  The color isn't a perfect match, so I know where they are.  Also, the 4" screws I bought are too long, so I'd have to head back to the store and buy more.  Is this necessary?  Do I risk life and limb by not removing those screws and replacing them with the gold ones?

Comment: That's funny, I had a HD employee tell me that coarse threaded drywall screws were fine for any regular wood screw application other than use in treated lumber and/or outside use. Drywall screws are a bit weaker than regular wood screws though - they shear easier.

Answer (score 5):

II would say you are fine (and you may have been fine before, who knows). You have replaced the screws that hold the cabinets to the studs, and those are the ones that hold the cabinets up. The ones in the face just keep the faces flush, so if one ever breaks, do the repair then.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can use drywall anchors like this:
[image]

https://youtu.be/kFLxQ9aNlrY?t=76
or the toggle anchor, they are very strong and if installed currectly, 4 of them will probably allow you to sit on that cabinet

Comment: OP is asking about the screws that hold drywall to studs, not methods of holding other objects onto drywall.

Comment: He is asking about kitchen cabinets that were screwed to drywall and stud behind the dry wall.